# Small issue on CSS

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I try to add a bootstrap dropdown in my page, but I have a problem with the top part of the dropdown, I think is something related with shadows, maybe someone can help me with this?

[image]

**HTML:**

```
<ul class="links-dropdown links">
    <li class="dropdown Inloggen">
        <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user pull-left"></span><b class="caret"></b></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="menu1" style="width: 300px;">
            <li style="width: 100%"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-right pull-left"></span><a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('customer/account/') ?>" class="dropdown-toggle"><?php echo $this->__('Account Dashboard') ?></a></li>
            <li style="width: 100%"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-right pull-left"></span><a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('customer/account/edit/') ?>" class="dropdown-toggle"><?php echo $this->__('Account Information') ?></a></li>
            <li style="width: 100%"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-right pull-left"></span><a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('customer/address/') ?>" class="dropdown-toggle"><?php echo $this->__('Address Book') ?></a></li>
            <li style="width: 100%"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-right pull-left"></span><a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('sales/order/history/') ?>" class="dropdown-toggle"><?php echo $this->__('My Orders') ?></a></li>
            <li style="width: 100%"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-right pull-left"></span><a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('customer/account/logout') ?>" class="dropdown-toggle"><?php echo $this->__('Log Out') ?></a></li>
         </ul>
    </li>
    <?php else: ?>
        <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" id="alogin" class="top-link-last dropdown-toggle"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user pull-left"></span><span class="text"><?php echo $this->__('Account') ?></span></a></li>
    <?php endif; ?>
</ul>
```

**CSS:**

```css
.links-dropdown .dropdown-menu {
  border-radius: 0;
  box-shadow: 2px 1px 5px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  color: #30a5ff;
  font-size: 170%;
  font-weight: 600;
  left: -250px;
  line-height: 1em;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
}

.dropdown-menu:after {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  top: -40px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-right: 40px solid #ffffff;
  border-bottom: 40px solid #ffffff;
  border-left: 40px solid #ffffff;
  border-topt: 40px solid #ffffff;
  content: '';
  box-shadow: 2px 1px 5px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
```

Comment: Try messing with `z-index`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `box-shadow: 2px 1px 5px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);` from `.dropdown-menu:after` will solve your issue.

Or you should make change in shadow like:

```css
box-shadow: 1px 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
```

**[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0kfc2c6q/)**

Comment: Hi i remove the box-shadow, now in only white and the drop-down box it seems broken

Comment: @RobertD Then what is your expected output.

Comment: I think try `box-shadow: 1px 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);` in `.dropdown-menu:after` will give your expected output? https://jsfiddle.net/0kfc2c6q/

Comment: can you tell me something please? what is happen with that caret? when I put mouse over and the dropdown is open that caret is not visible.

Comment: @RobertD Sorry i didn't understood that.

Comment: this <b class="caret"></b> is inside at the a tag

Comment: Ohh Ok. That's hide behind the dropdown.

Comment: yes, and I don't know how i can access it, maybe is a z-index problem

Comment: @RobertD. Give `position:relative` and `z-index: 1111;` to `.caret`

Comment: yes but what is the structure in the css? to access it? because I can;t name just .caret, bbecause is a part of bootstrap

Comment: you have right, I solved with position: relative; thank you so much Ketan :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `z-index` to `.dropdown-menu`:

```css
.dropdown-menu {
  z-index:100;
}
```